# Managing Memory with Python Reading Objects of Varying Sizes from OODB's

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection

I'm reading in a collection of objects (tables like sqlite3 tables or dataframes) from an Object Oriented DataBase, most of which are small enough that the Python garbage collector can handle without incident. However, when they get larger in size (less than 10 MB's) the GC doesn't seem to be able to keep up.

psuedocode looks like this:

```
walk = walkgenerator('/path')
objs = objgenerator(walk)
with db.transaction(bundle=True, maxSize=10000, maxParts=10): 
    oldobj = None
    oldtable = None
    for obj in objs:
        currenttable = obj.table
        if oldtable and oldtable in currenttable:
            db.delete(oldobj.path)
        del oldtable
        oldtable = currenttable
        del oldobj
        oldobj = obj
        if not count % 100:
            gc.collect()
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to manage memory while allowing Python to handle it when possible.

Perhaps embarrassingly, I've tried using del to help clean up reference counts.

I've tried gc.collect() at varying modulo counts in my for loops:

- 100 (no difference),
- 1 (slows loop quite a lot, and I will still get a memory error of some type),
- 3 (loop is still slow but memory still blows up eventually)

Suggestions are appreciated!!!

Particularly, if you can give me tools to assist with introspection. I've used Windows Task Manager here, and it seems to more or less randomly spring a memory leak. I've limited the transaction size as much as I feel comfortable, and that seems to help a little bit.

Comment: I don't do a lot of memory manipulation in python but if you are looking for low level memory control try the ctypes module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not enough info here to say much, but what I do have to say wouldn't fit in a comment so I'll post it here ;-)

First, and most importantly, in CPython garbage collection is *mostly* based on reference counting.  `gc.collect()` won't do anything for you (except burn time) unless trash objects are involved in reference cycles (an object `A` can be reached from itself by following a chain of pointers transitively reachable from `A`).  You create no reference cycles *in the code you showed*, but perhaps the database layer does.

So, after you run `gc.collect()`, does memory use go down at all?  If not, running it is pointless.

I expect it's most likely that the database layer is holding references to objects longer than necessary, but digging into that requires digging into exact details of how the database layer is implemented.

One way to get clues is to print the result of `sys.getrefcount()` applied to various large objects:

```
>>> import sys
>>> bigobj = [1] * 1000000
>>> sys.getrefcount(bigobj)
2
```

As the docs say, the result is generally 1 larger than you might hope, because the refcount of `getrefcount()`'s argument is temporarily incremented by 1 simply because it *is* being used (temporarily) as an argument.

So if you see a refcount greater than 2, `del` won't free the object.

Another way to get clues is to pass the object to `gc.get_referrers()`.  That returns a list of objects that directly refer to the argument (provided that a referrer participates in Python's cyclic gc).

BTW, you need to be clearer about what you mean by "doesn't seem to work" and "blows up eventually".  Can't guess.  What *exactly* goes wrong?  For example, is `MemoryError` raised?  Something else?  Traebacks often yield a world of useful clues.